# Modify start up routine of LXDE using startx command

Tags: linux, x11, lxde, framebuffer, yocto

I have built lxde and fbtft driver for Raspberry Pi using Yocto. In order to correctly start X11 session and dbus, I need to stop the existing one and execute something like:

```
FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 startx
```

I want to automize this and make sure that this is what is executed from the beginning, not just

```
startx
```

Any guidance how I can modify this command (through a script or a config file or even from inside Yocto) is much appreciated.

Comment: Write a wrapper script called `startx` and place it somewhere that's earlier in your `PATH` than the `startx` binary?

Comment: Where can I actually access the place startx is called?